# getting the output Optional("test")

Tags: ios, swift

I tried the following code

```
if let shortURL = shortURL { 
     var url = "\(shortURL.absoluteString)" 
     MUser.sharedInstance.setMobileReferralId(url) 
     self.referralLink.text = url self.copyToClipboard() 
}
```

For the url variable, I get the output Optional("Test"). How do I remove the "Optional" part?

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: You extend the if, `if let shortURL = shortURL, let url = "\(shortURL.absoluteString)" {`

Answer (score 0):

The reason looks like `absoluteString` is optional so you can provide a default value or using if let to assign its value to url, like below

```
if let url = shortURL.absoluteString {
    print(url)
}
```

or provide some default blank value like

```
var url = shortURL.absoluteString ?? ""
print(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove the `Optional` part, you only need to unwrap optional right. example:

```swift
if let shortURL = shortURL,  
    let url = shortURL.absoluteString {
    print(url)
}
```